# Got multiple problems: can't populate option component with answers, stays empty all the time. Also handleShowScore does not work either

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

//Database://

const qData = [
{
id: 0,
question: "hey",
answers: [
{ value: 1, text: "rafael" },
{ value: 2, text: "dontaelo" },
{ value: 3, text: "leonardo" },
{ value: 4, text: "michelangelo" }
]
},
{
id: 1,
question: "hey hey",
answers: [
{ value: 1, text: "rafael" },
{ value: 2, text: "dontaelo" },
{ value: 3, text: "leonardo" },
{ value: 4, text: "michelangelo" }
]
}
];

export default qData;

//And the App itself//

class PersonalityQuiz extends React.Component {
state = {
score: 0
};

```
handleShowScore = e => {
    // const { answer } = this.state;
    let a = qData.querySelectorAll("select");
    let newScore = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        newScore = newScore + parseInt(a[i].answers.value, 10);
    }

    this.setState({
        score: newScore
    });
};
```

//here i try populate option component with answer's text, so that based on chosen answer you calculate your total score//

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Quiz</h1>
            <p>Select your favorite of each of the following choices:</p>
            <div>
                {qData.map((item, index) => (
                    <li key={index}>
                        {item.question}
                        <select>
                            <option value="item.answer">{item.answers.text}</option>
                        </select>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </div>
            <button onClick={this.handleShowScore}>Show Score</button>

            <p id="score">You total score is {this.state.score} points.</p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}
ReactDOM.render(, document.querySelector("#root"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is, that you are currently only populating the questions, but not the answers. You are using `item.answers.text` to create the answer, but this doesn't exist, as `item.answers` is an array.
Solution: Map over the answer-array

```js
{qData.map((item, index) => (
    <li key={index}>
        {item.question}
        <select>
            {item.answers.map((answer) => (
                <option value={answer.value}>{answer.text}</option>
            )}
        </select>
    </li>
))}
```